# Key stroke not working in wpf dialog when launched from Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, modal-dialog, focus, keystroke

I have an application where on the click of a button in winforms I launch a WPF dialog using `ShowDialog()`.

The issue what i am facing is related to key strokes. when i press a key after launching the WPF dialog, the key stroke is not handled at the WPF dialog level, instead it passes on to the winform from where dialog was launched and as such the desired operation what i have inside the keyevent handler in WPFis escaped. How do i stop this? I tried using `dispatchHelper` but it did not work out.

Comment: interesting, does WPF dialog get focus?

Comment: yes , the dialog is getting focus and i am able to do all the operations in the dialog, only thing that is not happening is - able to get the key event , even if i put a debug point at the event handler and attach it to the app, it does not hit there instead the similar event handler in the winform (parent form from where i am launching the WPF dialog) is getting hit.

Comment: I am trying to perform some operation on press of key- "B" in both parent form and wpf dialog.If the focus is on parent winform, then i expect an event handler in Winform to be called and if the focus is on wpf dialog, then i expect the wpf event handler to be called, which is not happening. always the parent form event handler is getting called